# Connecting to IIS 8 from Safari 5.1.7 by WebSocket

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, safari, websocket

My IE, Chrome, Chrome androud, Opera, Firefox browsers successfully connected to my IIS by WebSocket. See an example:

**The handshake from the client looks as follows:**

*GET /SimpleChatApplication/ChatHandler.ashx HTTP/1.1*

*Host: pc2014:80*

*Connection: Upgrade*

*Pragma: no-cache*

*Cache-Control: no-cache*

*Upgrade: websocket*

*Origin: http//pc2014*

*Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13*

*User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36*

*Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch*

*Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6*

*Sec-WebSocket-Key: rrKYVVaPKmMnINtsUh9BNg==*

*Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits*

**The handshake from the server looks as follows:**

*HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols*

*Cache-Control: private*

*Upgrade: Websocket*

*Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5*

*X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319*

*Sec-WebSocket-Accept: IQ/qcgyu36N/d1p0JEU7nZ3W8Vo=*

*Connection: Upgrade*

*X-Powered-By: ASP.NET*

*Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 23:54:37 GMT*

**But if I use Safary bowser then:**

**The handshake from the client looks as follows:**

*GET /SimpleChatApplication/ChatHandler.ashx HTTP/1.1*

*Upgrade: WebSocket*

*Connection: Upgrade*

*Host: pc2014:80*

*Origin: http://pc2014*

*Sec-WebSocket-Key1: N9 Q32K\275z 5z  < 1=  2 c*

*Sec-WebSocket-Key2: -1 z 6#HA g)1Aue0483 420d*

**The handshake from the server looks as follows:**

*HTTP/1.1 200 OK*

*Cache-Control: private*

*Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5*

*X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319*

*X-Powered-By: ASP.NET*

*Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 23:56:19 GMT*

*Content-Length: 0*

*HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request*

*Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii*

*Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0*

*Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 23:56:19 GMT*

*Connection: close*

*Content-Length: 326*

---

Bad Request

### Bad Request - Invalid Verb

HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.

---

Please explain me where is error? Or Safary sends incorrect request, or IIS recognizes incorrectly.

I have used [www.websocket.org](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) site for testing. I have replaced the server address from "ws://echo.websocket.org" to my IIS address before testing

Comment: I feel it's some error in the code. Not the browser issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828726

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Safari implements an old version of the WebSocket standard, named [hybi](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol).

Apparently ASP.NET only supports the definitive one, [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). That is the version that major browsers use as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) library. ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.